# Column name with spaces in tarql

Tags: csv, sparql, rdf, triples

I am using tarql (https://github.com/tarql/tarql) - uses sparql syntax - to transform CSV data into RDF triples.

I have a column name "web site". How can i bind to the variable using BIND function? I tried a lot of ways, but i didn't find the solution:

```
BIND (?web site AS ?homepage)
BIND (?"web site" AS ?homepage)
BIND (?'web site' AS ?homepage)
BIND (?web\ site AS ?homepage)
```

All leading to parse error.

Comment: According to https://github.com/tarql/tarql/blob/master/src/main/java/org/deri/tarql/CSVParser.java#L76 it should be underscore, i.e. `BIND (?web_site AS ?homepage)` . Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, and can i escape ','?

Comment: What do you mean? A comma in the column name? If you have a look at the source code (https://github.com/tarql/tarql/blob/master/src/main/java/org/deri/tarql/CSVParser.java#L73-L81), white space, hyphen and question mark will be replaced by an underscore, all other depend on whether Apache Jena can parse the string. But there is also a FIXME entry, i.e. some characters might not be allowed.

Comment: Yes I mean header like:
"column1;column2;column3, and something to column3;column4"

Comment: Given that the delimiter is `;`, the string to convert to a variable would be "column3, and something to column3". Which would result in "column3,_and_something_to_column3" by the `replace` line. I don't know if `Var.alloc` from Apache Jena can parse this string. You should get an exception if it doesn't work, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have to deal with complicated situations my suggestion is: first try with an exploratory tests; Let's see by example:

suppose your source data file is: `./table/table.csv` which contains:

```
main index;web site;title, to translate
1;"ciao.ronda.com";"this is the first"
2;"miao.ronda.it";"this is the second"
3;"bao.ronda.uk";"this is the third"
```

#### step1: explorative test query `qstar.sparql`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM <file:table.csv#delimiter=%3B;>
  WHERE {}
  LIMIT 100
```

lancher example:

```
#!/bin/bash -
table=./data/table.csv
query=./data/qstar.sparql 
./bin/tarql --test  --delimiter \; --header-row --verbose ${query} ${table}
```

result:

```
 $ ./launcher0.sh
--------------------------------------------------------
| main_index | web_site         | title,_to_translate  |
========================================================
| "1"        | "ciao.ronda.com" | "this is the first"  |
| "2"        | "miao.ronda.it"  | "this is the second" |
| "3"        | "bao.ronda.uk"   | "this is the third"  |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

well now we know the third column **variable name** computed with these options is: `title,_to_translate`

#### step2: test if the syntax of BIND statement is supported with the proceeds variable name ( `title,_to_translate` in our example )

here we need an example `BIND` based query to understand the problem; suppose this is the query where we try to use out field named: `?title,_to_translate`

```
SELECT ?homepage ?uri ?title_with_language_tag
  WHERE {
    BIND (?web_site AS ?homepage)
    BIND (URI(CONCAT('http://website.com/ns#', ?main_index)) AS ?uri)
    BIND (STRLANG(?title,_to_translate, 'en') AS ?title_with_language_tag)
  }
```

result:

```
 $ ./launcher0.sh
com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Lexical error at line 5, column 27.  Encountered: "t" (116), after : "_"
    at org.deri.tarql.TarqlParser.parse(TarqlParser.java:113)
```

in short this query contains a **Lexical error** that is not supported by `ena.query.QueryParser`

In cases like this, rather than continue to fight with the language, I prefer to adopt a little workaround

#### step3: solution with a little workaround

let's leverage on the option `-H   --no-header-row   CSV file has no header row; use variable names ?a, ?b, ...` and enjoy an easy solution; all we need todo is remove the first head row from the content our source data file ( this is an easy task you can pipeline to the process or do in the ways you prefer) for convenience of testing I copied data without the first column in `./data/table0-noheader.csv`.

now the same query become easier for the parser; 
`./data/query0.sparql`:

```
SELECT ?homepage ?uri ?title_with_language_tag
  WHERE {
    BIND (?a AS ?homepage)
    BIND (URI(CONCAT('http://website.com/ns#', ?b)) AS ?uri)
    BIND (STRLANG(?c, 'en') AS ?title_with_language_tag)
  }
```

launcher-noheader.sh:

```
!/bin/bash -
table=./data/table0-noheader.csv
query=./data/query0.sparql 
./bin/tarql --test  --no-header-row --delimiter \; --header-row --verbose ${query} ${table}
```

result:

```
 $ ./launcher-noheader.sh 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| homepage | uri                                    | title_with_language_tag |
===============================================================================
| "1"      | <http://website.com/ns#ciao.ronda.com> | "this is the first"@en  |
| "2"      | <http://website.com/ns#miao.ronda.it>  | "this is the second"@en |
| "3"      | <http://website.com/ns#bao.ronda.uk>   | "this is the third"@en  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note

1. the reference docs: 
   [Header row, delimiters, quotes and character encoding in CSV/TSV files](http://tarql.github.io) states all the possible ways and combinations to express options: is a good read worth.
2. another useful reference could be: 
   [Possible names for variables](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rVARNAME) in *SPARQL 1.1 Query Language*